# Set background image but leave all text in front

Tags: html, css

I want to set the entire `main` to have a background-image without effecting the text or input fields I have.

```
<body>
   <main>
   <img src="/images/auto-repair.jpg" alt="repair">
   <div>
       Something Here
   </div>
</body>
```

In CSS, if I change opacity, it changes the font too

```
body img {
   opacity: 0.5;
   position: absolute;
}
```

I am using bootstrap too - if that matters.

Comment: What font changes and how?

Comment: Everything I have in that ```<div>``` becomes opaque also. I'm using handlebars.js to render into the div, or else I'd share the content too.

Comment: You can do as the answer suggests, or you would need to position the div absolutely too, and set a higher z-index.

Answer (score 0):

I think you should just do this:

```
main{ background: url('/images/auto-repair.jpg');}
```

If you want to modify the opacity, you can use normal flow for all the elements and then a negative margin for < div>:

```
div {
    margin-top: -100vh;
}
```